# Installing softare on Linux

Tags: apt-get, redhat-enterprise-linux, make

I'm trying to install the GMP package on Redhat 4, x86_64. The package can only be installed using make, which is not available and should be installed with apt-get/yum, but I don't have either one of them. I tried installing them using rpm, but they each require lots of dependencies themselves, which although finite in amount seem like a VERY tedious job to do.

Any help on how I should go about solving this?

Comment: This is clearly not a programming question.

Comment: yum groupinstall “Development Tools”

Comment: redhat **4** ? just install a fresh OS...

Comment: he might mean RHEL 4

Comment: It can't be redhat 4! Not if it is x86_64. (can it?)

Comment: It's probably RHEL 4 then, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you install yum manually via rpm?

> ### Manually install YUM via RPM in Centos 5
>
> To manually reinstall yum, run the following commands:
>
> ```
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/gmp-4.1.4-10.el5.x86_64.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/readline-5.1-3.el5.x86_64.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-2.4.3-27.el5.x86_64.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.2.8.x86_64.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/libxml2-python-2.6.26-2.1.2.8.x86_64.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/expat-1.95.8-8.3.el5_4.2.x86_64.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.x86_64.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/sqlite-3.3.6-5.x86_64.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-sqlite-1.1.7-1.2.1.x86_64.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/elfutils-libelf-0.137-3.el5.x86_64.rpm
> rpm –nodeps -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/elfutils-0.137-3.el5.x86_64.rpm
> rpm –nodeps -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/rpm-4.4.2.3-18.el5.x86_64.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/rpm-python-4.4.2.3-18.el5.x86_64.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/m2crypto-0.16-6.el5.6.x86_64.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-urlgrabber-3.1.0-5.el5.noarch.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-3.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-iniparse-0.2.3-4.el5.noarch.rpm
> rpm –nodeps -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/yum-fastestmirror-1.1.16-14.el5.centos.1.noarch.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/yum-3.2.22-26.el5.centos.noarch.rpm
> yum -y update
> ```

[Source](http://www.nightlion.net/guides/2010/manually-install-yum-via-rpm-in-centos-5/)

Comment: I already tried that, but the links are broken...

Answer (score 1):

RHEL4 does not have yum. On that version you use up2date to install software if you are subscribed to Red Hat's software channels.

Answer (score 0):

Redhat 4 is pretty old (1996), so the modern tools which automatically download dependencies aren't available.

The system was probably installed from a DVD or a set of CD ROMs. Find those. That way, you will at least have all the files readily available.

Or you can try this [recipe to install yum on Redhat 4](http://blog.eukhost.com/webhosting/install-yum-utility-on-redhat-4/).

Note: Unless there is a really good reason to keep this ancient system alive, consider upgrading to a more recent version. Linux systems are pretty secure but that's only true as long as you install every update. If that system is connected to the Internet, chances are that it's not your own system anymore ...

Comment: he might mean RHEL 4

Comment: I'm not sure how I got confused. Misinformation deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can download make directly from the [GNU website](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/). You should also install a C compiler such as `gcc`.